# Square roots modulo $pq$ where $p$, $q$ are distinct primes - confusion with quote

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have a doubt about the following quote from a book:

> The Chinese Remainder Theorem implies that, if $p$ and $q$ are
>   distinct primes, then $s$ is a square modulo $pq$ if and only if $s$
>   is a square modulo $p$ and $s$ is a square modulo $q$. In particular,
>   if $s \equiv x^2 \equiv (x')^2 \pmod p$ where $x \neq x'$, and
>   likewise $x \equiv y^2 \equiv (y')^2 \pmod q$, then $s$ has exactly
>   four square roots modulo $pq$, namely,
>
> $$s \equiv (xy)^2 \equiv (x'y)^2 \equiv (xy')^2 \equiv (x'y')^2 \pmod{pq}$$

As an attempt to understand the quote, suppose I want to find the square roots of $11$ modulo $133$. So, I have $s = 11$, and, since $133 = 7 \times 19$, I have $p = 7$ and $q = 19$. I first need to separately find the roots of $11$ modulo $7$ and of $11$ modulo $19$:

1. To find the roots modulo $7$, solve $x^2 \equiv 11 \pmod 7$. Since $11 \equiv 2^2 \equiv 5^2 \pmod{7}$, the roots are $x = 2$ and $x' = 5$.
2. To find the roots modulo $19$, solve $x^2 \equiv 11 \pmod{19}$. Since $11 \equiv 7^2 \equiv 12^2 \pmod{19}$, the roots are $y = 7$ and $y' = 12$.

The quote is saying that $xy$, $x'y$, $xy'$ and $x'y'$ are roots of $s$ modulo $pq$. However, this seems to be untrue in my example:

- $xy = 2 \times 7 = 14$, but $11 \not\equiv 14^2 \pmod{133} $.
- $xy' = 2 \times 12 = 24$, but $11 \not\equiv 24^2 \pmod{133} $.
- $x'y = 5 \times 7 = 35$, but $11 \not\equiv 35^2 \pmod{133} $
- $x'y' = 5 \times 12 = 60$, but $11 \not\equiv 60^2 \pmod{133} $

Am I missing something?

Comment: $n\equiv\pm2\bmod7$ and $n\equiv\pm7\bmod19\implies n\equiv\pm12$ or $\pm 26\bmod133$

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything. The quoted text looks wrong to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chinese remainder theorem must be applied correctly.

In your example, it says that there is exactly one $a \pmod{133}$ such that $a \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$ and $a \equiv 7 \pmod{19}$. See, for example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement).

Since we have $1 = 3 * 19 - 8 * 7$, we put $a = 2 * 3 * 19 - 7 * 8 * 7 = -278$ and find that, indeed $a^2 \equiv 11 \pmod{133}$. An explanation of this calculation, can be found, for example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Existence_(constructive_proof)).

Similar calculations for the other combinations of roots of $11$ mod $7$ and $19$ produce the following four distinct roots of $11$ mod $133$.

$$a \equiv 121 \pmod{133}$$

$$b \equiv 107 \pmod{133}$$

$$ c \equiv 26 \pmod{133}$$

$$ d \equiv 12 \pmod{133}$$